# Build bot for a WebGL/Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, webgl, bots

There is a card game that can be played in the browser (through a WebGL application) or with Steam. I would like to improve my machine learning skills by developing a bot that can play this game automatically. I think the developers don't provide an API for that.

Can I do that in some way? How can I get data from the game application (for example, capturing data from "screenshot")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the data from screenshots is possible but you will need to recognise every single card. For example you could take the color value of a few pixels on every card and map the combination to the card. Depending on how many cards there are and how different each card is, you will need more or less pixels. With this database you will have to check every place on the screen where a card could be played (assuming cards are always placed in the same location) and check the pixels to find the played card. You will also need a similar process for other relevant information that is needed by the bot (e.G. the players and the enemies health points).

There is a tutorial in Python for this process here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-python-bot-that-can-play-web-games--active-11117

Another option is finding the values in the computers memory. I fear, I can't provide you any help for this.

Be careful though, developing/using a bot is most certainly against the terms and conditions of the game and may result in a ban if it is detected by the developers.